# glutDisplayFunc() doesn't draw but normal function call does

Tags: opengl, glut, freeglut

I am unable to display a simple moving triangle on the screen, and it only happens when I call my function with glutDisplayFunc(render). If I call my function like a normal call render() it display the triangle well but in this case it doesn't animate my triangle.

So basically I have two issues:

1. can't draw triangle when call function with glutDisplayFunc(render)
2. can't animate triangle when function call like render() but it can draw triangle though.

below is my main and display code:

```
void render()
{

currentTime = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

GLfloat color[] = { (float)sin(currentTime) * 0.5f + 0.5f, (float)cos(currentTime) * 0.5f + 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, color);

GLfloat attrib[] = { (float)sin(currentTime) * 0.5f, (float)cos(currentTime) * 0.6f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

glVertexAttrib4fv(0, attrib);
// Use the program object we created earlier for rendering

glUseProgram(rendering_program);

//Draw triangle
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3);

glutSwapBuffers();

}
```

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
glutInitWindowSize(600,600);
glutInitContextVersion(4,3);
glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
glutCreateWindow("Shader");

if (glewInit()) {
 cerr << "Unable to initialize GLEW ... exiting" << endl;
 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 startup();
// render();     // WORKS FINE AND DRAW TRIANGLE
 glutDisplayFunc(render);    //DOESN'T DRAW TRIANGLE
 shutdown();

glutMainLoop();
return 0;

}
```

I believe the shaders are compiled well and there is no error in that part of the code because it is drawing triangle without glutDisplayFunc(); and the only problem is when I use glutDisplayFunc(render); nothing is drawn.

Where am I going wrong? And how can I fix the two issues I mentioned above?

Comment: You are aware that you're calling `shutdown()` before entering the `glutMainLoop()`, right? There is absolutely no reason why the callback should not be invoked with the code you show us and I bet that if you set a break point in `render()`, the debugger will run into that at least once unless, of course, you unregister the callback again in `shutdown()`...

Comment: omg I didn't even realize that. ! It works now. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glutDisplayFunc` does not render itself. It registers a function that should be used by glut when rendering has to be done. The call ifsef happens somewhere inside the `glutMainLoop()`. Since you are shutting down everything before starting the rendering process, the data is not available when the system tries to render.

Comment: You have explained it really well. I completely understood why I was having that issue now. Thank you for your prompt response its working now :)